# Problem importing fonts with FPDF using python

Tags: python, pyfpdf

I've been trying to import specialty fonts beyond what is default included with the FPDF package with Python, using the `pdf.add_font()` command. The code below produces an error of an Undefined font, as though I didn't just use `pdf.add_font()`. Below you can find a sample of my code, as well as proof that the relevant fonts are in the directory specified in the `pdf.add_font()` command. I have also tried installing the relevant fonts in the `C:\Windows\Fonts` directory.

```
from fpdf import FPDF

# Makes new pdf
nbareport = FPDF('P', 'mm', 'Letter')

# Imports new fonts
nbareport.add_font('CMU Serif', '', r'C:\Users\gregd\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf\cmu.serif-roman.ttf', uni=True)
nbareport.add_font('CMU Serif', 'B', r'C:\Users\gregd\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\Lib\site-packages\matplotlib\mpl-data\fonts\ttf\cmunbx.ttf', uni=True)

# Create instance of FPDF class
# Letter size paper, use inches as unit of measure
nbareport = FPDF(format='letter', unit='in')

nbareport.set_font('CMU Serif', '', 10)
nbareport.cell('Hello World!')
nbareport.output('test.pdf', 'F')
```

Relevant error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\gregd\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\NBA Data\FPDF tester.py", line 14, in <module>
    nbareport.set_font('CMU Serif', '', 10)
  File "C:\Users\gregd\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\lib\site-packages\fpdf\fpdf.py", line 603, in set_font
    self.error('Undefined font: '+family+' '+style)
  File "C:\Users\gregd\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2\venv\lib\site-packages\fpdf\fpdf.py", line 227, in error
    raise RuntimeError('FPDF error: '+msg)
RuntimeError: FPDF error: Undefined font: cmu serif
```

[Proof of fonts in the correct directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VobCZ.png)

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line:

```
nbreport = FPDF(format='letter', unit='in')
```

creates a brand-new FPDF instance and helpfully deletes the one in which you so carefully added the fonts.  You need to add the fonts to the instance you're actually using.

Comment: Great thank you! Sometimes having another set of eyes can be helpful.

Comment: This solved mi issue, thanks Tim!